# How to test if styles are dynamically applied on a React component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, radium

I've written a React component, `Button`:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Radium from 'radium'
import React from 'react'

import { Icon } from 'components'
import { COLOURS, GLOBAL_STYLES, ICONS, MEASUREMENTS } from 'app-constants'

@Radium
export default class Button extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.string,
    dark: PropTypes.bool,
    icon: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(ICONS)).isRequired,
    style: PropTypes.object,
  }

  render() {
    const { children, dark, icon, style } = this.props
    let mergedStyles = Object.assign({}, styles.base, style)

    if (!children)
      mergedStyles.icon.left = 0

    if (dark)
      mergedStyles = Object.assign(mergedStyles, styles.dark)

    return (
      <button
        className="btn btn-secondary"
        style={mergedStyles}
        tabIndex={-1}>
        <Icon name={icon} style={mergedStyles.icon} />
        {children &&
          <span style={mergedStyles.text}>{children}</span>
        }
      </button>
    )
  }
}

export const styles = {
  base: {
    backgroundColor: COLOURS.WHITE,
    border: `1px solid ${COLOURS.BORDER_LIGHT}`,
    borderRadius: GLOBAL_STYLES.BORDER_RADIUS,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    padding: GLOBAL_STYLES.BUTTON_PADDING,

    ':focus': {
      outline: 'none',
    },

    ':hover': {
      boxShadow: GLOBAL_STYLES.BOX_SHADOW,
    },

    icon: {
      fontSize: GLOBAL_STYLES.ICON_SIZE_TINY,
      left: '-3px',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
    },

    text: {
      fontSize: GLOBAL_STYLES.FONT_SIZE_TINY,
      fontWeight: GLOBAL_STYLES.FONT_2_WEIGHT_MEDIUM,
      marginLeft: `${MEASUREMENTS.BUTTON_PADDING.HORIZONTAL}px`,
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
    },
  },

  dark: {
    backgroundColor: COLOURS.PRIMARY_3,
    border: `1px solid ${COLOURS.PRIMARY_2}`,
    color: COLOURS.WHITE,

    ':hover': {
      boxShadow: GLOBAL_STYLES.BOX_SHADOW_DARK,
    },
  },
}
```

I've also written a test for `Button` with Jest and Enzyme, which validates if its `dark` styles are applied when its `dark` prop is set to `true`:

```js
import { ICONS } from 'app-constants'
import Button, { styles } from 'components/Button'

describe("<Button>", () => {
  let props
  let mountedComponent
  const getComponent = () => {
    if (!mountedComponent)
      mountedComponent = shallow(
        <Button {...props} />
      )
    return mountedComponent
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    mountedComponent = undefined
    props = {
      children: undefined,
      dark: undefined,
      icon: ICONS.VIBE,
      style: undefined,
    }
  })

  describe("when `dark` is `true`", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      props.dark = true
    })

    it("applies the component's `dark` styles", () => {
      const componentStyles = getComponent().props().style
      expect(componentStyles).toEqual(expect.objectContaining(styles.dark))
    })
  })
})
```

As you can see, I do this by checking if the properties of `styles.dark` are inside the rendered `Button`'s `style` attribute. If they are, then it means the styles have applied successfully.

The issue is that `styles.dark` and `componentStyles` don't match:

#### Output of `console.log(styles.dark)`

```js
ObjectContaining{  
   ":hover": {  
      "boxShadow": "0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"
   },
   "backgroundColor": [Object],
   "border": "1px solid rgb(47, 52, 63)",
   "color": [Object]
}
```

#### Output of `console.log(componentStyles)`

```
{  
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(31, 34, 40)",
    "border": "1px solid rgb(47, 52, 63)",
    "borderRadius": "4px",
    "color": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "padding": "3px 5px 3px 5px"
}
```

I notice a few issues here:

- `styles.dark` has several `Color()` `[Object]`s from the `color` library. They haven't outputted their `rgb()` value as a string, but the same properties in `componentStyles` have, thus resulting in a mismatch.
- `componentStyles` has Radium's interactive styles stripped, such as `:focus` and `:hover` (I assume Radium does this during rendering triggered by Enzyme's `shallow()` function). This causes a mismatch with `styles.dark`, which doesn't have these properties stripped.

As a result, I'm not sure how to test this. I can't think of any alternative solutions to validate that `styles.dark` has been applied. I think that doing the following to `styles.dark` during testing would be a solution:

- Recursively cause all `Color()` `[Object]`s to process so they output their `rgb()` value as a string.
- Recursively remove all interactive Radium styles (like `:focus` and `:hover`)

Doing so would cause `styles.dark` to equal the value of `componentStyles`, thus passing the test. I'm just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to this a few days later with fresh eyes and thought of a solution:

```js
describe("<Button>", () => {
  let props
  let mountedComponent
  let defaultComponent
  const getComponent = () => {
    if (!mountedComponent)
      mountedComponent = shallow(
        <Button {...props} />
      )
    return mountedComponent
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      children: undefined,
      dark: undefined,
      icon: ICONS.VIBE,
      style: undefined,
    }
    defaultComponent = getComponent()
    mountedComponent = undefined
  })

  describe("when `dark` is `true`", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      props.dark = true
    })

    it("applies the component's `dark` styles", () => {
      const darkStyles = getComponent().props().style
      expect(defaultComponent.props().style).not.toEqual(darkStyles)
    })
  })
})
```

Rather than asserting that the rendered component's `style` prop contains the `styles.dark` (which is brittle), it just checks to see if the styles have changed at all when the `dark` prop is set to `true`.